# What seems to be the error in my js code?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have a problem, i am stuck on a js assessment which is to create a silly story generator. Everything else is working fine but my .replace() string method seems to have an error tied to it. When the story is generating, the placeholder aren't being filled nor are the words changing like they are supposed to. Here is the code.

```
     const customName = document.getElementById('customname');
const randomize = document.querySelector('.randomize');
const story = document.querySelector('.story');

function randomValueFromArray(array){
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
  return array[random];
}

let insertX = ['Willy the Goblin',
    'Big Daddy',
    'Father Christmas'];
     let insertY = ['the soup kitchen',
        'Disneyland',
        'the White House'];
    let insertZ = ['spontaneously combusted',
        'melted into a puddle on the sidewalk',
        'turned into a slug and crawled away'];


let storyText = 'It was 94 fahrenheit outside, so :insertx: went for a walk. When they got to :inserty:, they stared in horror for a few moments, then :insertz:. Bob saw the whole thing, but was not surprised — :insertx: weighs 300 pounds, and it was a hot day.';
let newStory = storyText;
let xItem = randomValueFromArray(insertX) ;
let yItem = randomValueFromArray(insertY);
let zItem = randomValueFromArray(insertZ) ;

storyText.replace(':insertx:', xItem);
storyText.replace(':insertx:',xItem);
storyText.replace(':inserty:',yItem);
storyText.replace(':insertz:',zItem);
        randomize.addEventListener('click', result);

        

function result() {

  if(customName.value !== '') {
    let name = customName.value;
    newStory.replace('Bob', name)
  }

  if(document.getElementById("uk").checked) {
    let weight = Math.round(300 / 14) + ' stone';
    let temperature =  Math.round((94 - 32)*0.5556) + ' centigrade';
    newStory.replace('94 Farenheight', temperature)
    newStory.replace('300 pounds', weight)
  }

  story.textContent = newStory;
  story.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

I don't know what the error is but i presume that it is tied to the .replace() string method. Please help.

Comment: If anyone wants the HTML to run it, please post a reply asking for it. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the first argument of the `string.replace(a,b)` is a regex. If you give a plain string as the first argument, the function will replace only the first occurence. Change it to something like this:

```
storyText.replace(/:insertx:/i, xItem);
```